# Kivy gesture is registered on button

Tags: android, python, kivy, gesture

I try to make an android app using Kivy.
For swiping left and right I use ScreenManager and Gestures instead of Carousel. This approach derives from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934445/kivy-swiping-carousel-screenmanager) and I tried to make swiping possible in both directions.

While swiping works, however, when pressing any button this is also registered as gesture but it shouldn't. That means, most of the time when pressing the butten the event behind one of the gestures is also triggered.

I can somehow reduce the probability that this happens by increasing the `minscore` value, but that is not reliable and makes gestures less sensitive.

Is there a way to avoid this from happening? E.g. limiting the gesture recognition to the ScreenManager only?

I have attached an example of this app.

Many thanks!

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import NoTransition
import gesture_box as gesture
import time
import datetime


class Storage:
    memory = 0

class Demo(gesture.GestureBox):

    def init(self):
        today = time.localtime().tm_wday # 0 is Monday
        l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'six']
        Storage.memory = today
        return l[today]

    def screen_up(self):
        print Storage.memory

        l = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'six']
        try:
            for i in range(6):
                if Storage.memory == 5:
                    return l[Storage.memory]
                if Storage.memory == i:
                    Storage.memory = i + 1
                    return l[i]
        except:
            pass

    def screen_down(self):
        print Storage.memory

        l = ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
        try:
            for i in range(5, -1, -1):
                if Storage.memory == 0:
                    return l[Storage.memory]
                if Storage.memory == i:
                    Storage.memory = i - 1
                    return l[i]
        except:
            pass

    def do_something_1(self):
        print 'Something 1 was done.'

        self.display_1 = 'Something 1 on Monday'
        self.display_2 = 'Something 1 on Tuesday'
        self.display_3 = 'Something 1 on Wednesday'
        self.display_4 = 'Something 1 on Thursday'
        self.display_5 = 'Something 1 on Friday'
        self.display_6 = 'Something 1 on Weekend'

    def do_something_2(self):
        print 'Something 2 was done.'

        self.display_1 = 'Something 2 on Monday'
        self.display_2 = 'Something 2 on Tuesday'
        self.display_3 = 'Something 2 on Wednesday'
        self.display_4 = 'Something 2 on Thursday'
        self.display_5 = 'Something 2 on Friday'
        self.display_6 = 'Something 2 on Weekend'


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Demo()

    def on_pause(self):
        # Here you can save data if needed
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

**gesture_box.py**

```
from kivy.gesture import GestureDatabase
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.gesture import Gesture 

gesture_strings = {
    'left_to_right_line': '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',
    'right_to_left_line': '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'
        }

#This database can compare gestures the user makes to its stored     gestures 
#and tell us if the user input matches any of them.
gestures = GestureDatabase()
for name, gesture_string in gesture_strings.items():
    gesture = gestures.str_to_gesture(gesture_string)
    gesture.name = name
    gestures.add_gesture(gesture)

class GestureBox(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name in gesture_strings:
            self.register_event_type('on_{}'.format(name))
        super(GestureBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_left_to_right_line(self):
        pass

    def on_right_to_left_line(self):
        pass

#To recognize a gesture, you will need to start recording each individual event in the
#touch_down handler, add the data points for each call to touch_move , and then do the
#gesture calculations when all data points have been received in the touch_up handler.

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #create an user defined variable and add the touch coordinates 
        touch.ud['gesture_path'] = [(touch.x, touch.y)]    
        super(GestureBox, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['gesture_path'].append((touch.x, touch.y))
        super(GestureBox, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if 'gesture_path' in touch.ud:
            #create a gesture object
            gesture = Gesture()    
            #add the movement coordinates 
            gesture.add_stroke(touch.ud['gesture_path'])
            #normalize so thwu willtolerate size variations
            gesture.normalize()
            #minscore to be attained for a match to be true, default 0.3
            match = gestures.find(gesture, minscore=0.3)
            if match:
                print "{} happened".format(match[1].name)
                self.dispatch('on_{}'.format(match[1].name))
        super(GestureBox, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

**main.kv**

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
<Demo>:
    on_parent: manager.transition = NoTransition(); manager.current = root.init(); manager.transition = SlideTransition()
    #Handling the gesture event.
    on_left_to_right_line: manager.current = root.screen_down();  manager.transition.direction = 'right'
    on_right_to_left_line: manager.current = root.screen_up();  manager.transition.direction = 'left'

    display_1: 'Monday'
    display_2: 'Tuesday'
    display_3: 'Wednesday'
    display_4: 'Thursday'
    display_5: 'Friday'
    display_6: 'Weekend'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ScreenManager:
            size_hint_y: 80
            id: manager
            Screen:
                name: "one"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_1
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

            Screen:
                name: "two"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_2
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

            Screen:
                name: "three"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_3
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

            Screen:
                name: "four"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_4
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

            Screen:
                name: "five"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_5
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

            Screen:
                name: "six"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text: root.display_6
                        size_hint_y: 80
                        halign: 'center'
                        text_size: (800, None)
                        color: (1, 1, 0, 1)

        Button:
            size_hint_y: 10
            text: 'Do something 1'
            background_color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
            on_release: root.do_something_1()

        Button:
            size_hint_y: 10
            text: 'Do something 2'
            background_color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
            on_release: root.do_something_2()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use Carousel? It would solve your problem instantly, meanwhile reducing code length.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Due to this I found your recent post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265676/swapping-screens-with-motion-in-kivy). I didn't know it is that easy with Carousel. I read Carousel would ring a lot of trouble that is why I avoided it.

Comment: Also, take a look at [PageLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.pagelayout.html). Kivy provides an example in the [repository.](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/pagelayout.py)